# Where should I unbind ButterKnife 8.x.x in a ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, butterknife

I have a RecycleView.ViewHolder class which use ButterKnife annotations.

Should my code unbind() in this ViewHolder class too?

```
public class AView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    @BindView(R.id.a_text_view) TextView aText;

    public AView(final View view)
    {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view); // It returns an Unbinder, but where should I call its unbind()?
    }
}
```

The docs (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) does not talk about this issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

According to Jake Wharton, author of Butterknife, `unbind()` is only required for `Fragments`. See this comment on the issue tracker:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/879

> Q: In the `RecyclerView`, how do we unbind the `ViewHolder`?
>
> A: You don't need to. Only `Fragments` need to in `onDestroyView()`.

The reason being that

> [`ViewHolders`] don't outlive the associated view. A `Fragment` does.

In other words, because a `Fragment` may continue to exist after its `Views` are destroyed, you need to call `.unbind()` from a `Fragment` to release the reference to the `Views` (and allow the associated memory to be reclaimed).

With a `ViewHolder`, the lifecycle of the holder is the same as the `Views` it holds. In other words, the `ViewHolder` and its `Views` are destroyed at the same time, so there's never a lingering reference from one to the other that you need to manually clear.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an explanation WHEN and WHY to use `unbind()` method:

> #### BINDING RESET
>
> Fragments have a different view lifecycle than activities. When
>   binding a fragment in `onCreateView`, set the views to null in
>   `onDestroyView`. Butter Knife returns an `Unbinder` instance when you
>   call `bind` to do this for you. Call its `unbind` method in the
>   appropriate lifecycle callback.
>
> ```
> public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {
>   @BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;
>   @BindView(R.id.button2) Button button2;
>   private Unbinder unbinder;
>
>   @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
>     unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
>     // TODO Use fields...
>     return view;
>   }
>
>   @Override public void onDestroyView() {
>     super.onDestroyView();
>     unbinder.unbind();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> From: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#reset

so you don't need at all to `unbind` any view from `ViewHolder`.

Hope it will help

Comment: This only really explains 'when and why' to unbind Butterknife for fragments. It only tells us something about the ViewHolder by omission. As such, I don't think it's a comprehensive answer (neither is mine, to be fair).

Comment: IMO this hardly even explains the why (and by extension the ButterKnife docs as well). @TimMalseed's answer seems to do a better job of that.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in the doc, which demonstrates how to use this library in the ViewHolder:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.title) TextView name;
    @BindView(R.id.job_title) TextView jobTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
      ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
  }
```

So, there is no need to call unbind for your ViewHolder.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, they do](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#reset).
This is only needed for Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Jakewharton has mentioned clearly in his documention

https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Unbind should be called only for fragments and most importantly , it should be called in onDestroyView instead of DestroyView .

Answer (score 0):

Just use it :

```
@Override
public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    if (unbinder != null) {
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```